# jQuery ui map: how to add size to infowindow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-map

Does anyone know how to apply size to the info window? Thanks.

```
map_container.gmap('addMarker', markerOptions).click(function () {
   map_container.gmap('openInfoWindow', { 
      'content':this.description, 
       'size': WHAT GOES HERE?
    }, this);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved.

For anyone else, documentation is at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=sv-SE#InfoWindowOptions

```
map_container.gmap('addMarker', markerOptions).click(function () {
   map_container.gmap('openInfoWindow', { 
      'content':this.description, 
      'maxWidth': '200'
    }, this);
});
```